# Does a pair of "2 ton" axle stands support 2 tons together or they each support 2 tons?

Tags: maintenance, oil-change, jack, jack-stand

I bought a pair of axle stands that came as a set and it stated "2 ton" capacity on the box. Each axle stand has a sticker stating "2 ton" capacity.

Since they came as a pair, does that mean one axle stand supports 1 ton, or does each support the full 2 tons?

To be specific, these are the axle stands in question: https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/certified-axle-stands-pair-0090010p.html#srp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends.** It is **not** safe to assume that jack stands/axle stands are rated one way or another in all cases. There are cases where the weight rating is for the pair, such as [these Craftsman jack stands](https://www.sears.com/craftsman-3-ton-high-lift-jack-stands/p-00950159000P#) or [these Pittsburgh jack stands](https://www.harborfreight.com/3-ton-heavy-duty-jack-stands-38846.html).

Alternatively, some jack stand sets are rated per-stand, like [these Duralast ones](https://www.autozone.com/engine-and-vehicle-lift/jack-stand/duralast-1-pair-2-ton-jack-stand/487215_0_0).

There are a few ways to check. As a general rule, cheaper stands tend to advertise the capacity of the pair. For the Craftsman stands, the only place the rating is mentioned is in the sticker on the stands, which you can see in the product image. For the Duralast stands, there are a couple of indicators: the warranted capacity is "1 to 2.99 ton," indicating the pair has a higher capacity than 2 tons, and there's a line where the description explicitly says "Jack Stand Weight Capacity Per Stand (tons): 2."

For yours, there's no clear indication, other than "CanadianTireTeam" answered a question on the product page asking essentially what you're asking here with, "...the support capacity of each stand is 2-ton (for a total of 4 tons). I apologize for the potential confusion; however, the rated capacity (per stand) is detailed on the packaging and stands, as well as in the manual."

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question. I somehow missed the Q&A section of the product page that had the answer there. In any case, I had no issues jacking up my 3800lbs car today.

Comment: 1 ton is 2000 pounds, 2 Tons is 2000 lbs .. so 2 = 4000 pounds...

Comment: " 2 Tons is 2000 lbs " ???

Answer (score 2):

Each axle stand will be rated for 2 tons - but I would not use them at full capacity, (half or 3/4 only) just a habit of mine especially if they are "cheaper" ones.

Comment: Something to realize (which I'm sure you do), most vehicles will not weigh in excess of two tons ... two jack stands will support the entirety of almost any passenger vehicle. Most safety items like jack stands are rated far below their actual holding ability ... well, at least ones made where proper safety standards are not optional. Two tons, being 4k lbs (at least in the States) is a lot of weight. Anyway, with most, I'd agree, I'd not max out the weight.

Comment: In addition to the static load of the vehicle, there will be an additional live load if you are doing heavy torquing, pulling, or pounding. A strong sideways push can buckle one of the legs if you are at near capacity.

Comment: Just to pick one, a 2019 Subaru Outback with the 3.6 engine has a curb weight of 3865 pounds, rather close to two tons.  I think there will be a number of cars that exceed 4000 pounds, especially if there is a little cargo on board.

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturing quality of jack stands sometimes leaves things to be desired.  I have a pair of "4-ton" jackstands.  Still have the box.  They were expensive and sold by a large retailer.  One of the stands is not usable.  A small shift in the weight of a vehicle caused the stand to buckle, and it is unusable.  The vehicle was a 2800 lb compact.

This answer is a general caution to use your best judgment. As far as I could find out, there are no recognized standards for consumer grade jackstands.  In my case, I consider myself fortunate that there were no critical body parts under the stand as it folded down into a wedge that I now use to block a wheel from rolling.